# Prove that vertices of BFS differ by at most one level

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to prove that either all the vertices in the queue of BFS (breadth-first search) output from a graph $G$ have the same level in $T$ or they have exactly two levels, which are 1 apart and vertices with smaller levels are before vertices with a higher level.

I guess proving by induction will solve this issue by number of steps 2's in BFS algorithm. Can you show me your method to prove the above claim?

Comment: If a BFS is started in a path graph from one of the ends, all vertices will be on different levels. Shurely shome mishtake?

Comment: I think OP is talking about BFS implemented using a queue, and looking at this queue at any iteration of the algorithm.

Comment: @MathieuRund, right.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, I edited the original question by adding details to how to do it by induction.